# Rewriting with .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make URL's look better by using a RewriteRule in .htaccess, but it doesn't work.

This is the case. I have a root folder in which there is a PHP-file called pdf.php. The script in that file sends a PDF-file to the user, which name is given as a variable in the URL. The PDF-files are in a folder called pdf, placed in the root. That folder is protected so that it's only possible to get a PDF-file by using the script. All that for security reasons.

You can download the PDF-files when you go to http://example.com/pdf.php?file=pdf/File.pdf for instance, where pdf/File.pdf is the path to the PDF-file. That's working fine. I want it to work when you simply go to http://example.com/pdf/File.pdf, so that URL has to be rewritten to the one mentioned before.

I tried to make a RewriteRule using a generator, but it doesn't work.
The following rules are in the .htaccess-file in the folder pdf. Placing it in the root didn't work either.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pdf/([^/]*)$ /pdf.php?file=pdf/$1
```

The protection of the folder pdf is as follows.

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com/
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Comment: Attach a set of source and target URL you are after. What rule you gave so far?

Comment: I changed my post with the lines I have in the .htaccess-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# to convert spaces to hyphens
RewriteRule "^(pdf)/(\S*) +(.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(pdf/.+)$ /pdf.php?file=$1 [L,QSA,B,NC]
```

Comment: I did what you said, but it doesn't work. I still get the 403 error because of the fact the PDF-file is in a protected folder, which means the redirect doesn't work. Anything else I can try?

Comment: The protection lines are now in the first post. When I remove them, it seems like your RewriteRule works, but only for PDF-files with just one word in the file name. It doesn't work when the name has two or more words, divided by spaces. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately it's still the same.

Comment: I tried an URL like http://example.com/pdf/File%20name.pdf, in which the file name has two words. The error I get is a 404 which the PHP-file returns when the file in the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: It prints pdf/File so everything behind the space isn't taken to the variable.

Comment: Yes, I took it exactly as you said. I've tried over and over but it keeps returning only the first word.

Comment: There's not much in my .htaccess-file, and the rules I use aren't conflicting rules. I'll try some things and hope to fix it. Question remaining is why it doesn't work when I protect the folder the way I described in the first post?

Comment: Right, so probably the rule has to be rewritten a bit so that it can be placed in a .htaccess-file, also including the protection, placed in the folder pdf. What do you think? I tried different online tests and all of them do take all the words into the variable, but I can't get my server to do so. Is it a possibility to change the spaces to hyphens and let PHP change them back to spaces? Thanks for all your help anyway!

Comment: Either you can protect the folder OR you can forward to `pdf.php` but not both.

Comment: Thank you, good to know. Last question, can I change the spaces to hyphens so that http://example.com/pdf/File%20name.pdf becomes http://example.com/pdf.php?file=pdf/File-name.pdf for instance and then change them back with PHP so that in the script the variable becomes pdf/File name.pdf again? Not only working for two words of course, also three or more.